# # Unknown argument "name" on field "Mutation.updateAccountInfo"

Tags: graphql

I am newbie on graphql installed it and used little bit for get queries, here are differently defined mutation queries I used to read documentation and watched videos which are something like different from eg:

```
mutation {
      updateSomething(param1:"value1", param2:"value2"){
        param1,
        param2
      }
}
```

This is following example I got from project documentation file.

```
mutation UpdateAccountInfo($account: UpdateAccountInput!) {
    updateAccountInfo(account: $account)
}
```

Following example I am running on graphql to update account

```
mutation {
  updateAccountInfo(id:1,name: "abc", contactNumber: "321456", type: "1254", bio: "5142")
}
```

Following is input data defined in definition file.

```
input UpdateAccountInput {
  picture: String
  name: String
  contactNumber: String
  type: String
  bio: String
}
```